# Scan text file for duplicate id numbers and retain the lines with the highest date value deleting the others

Tags: text-processing, csv

I am working with a multi-line text file (.csv) that contains 7 columns.

Each line contains what "should" be a unique i.d. There are also some date columns, one of which is a "last modified" date.

I have found that what should be "unique" id's are actually repeated on occasion and it's a problem I need to resolve by removing all but one.

I have an example using gawk below but is there a way to use gawk, awk, or grep etc to delete any lines that are duplicated BUT with the exception of the "most recently" modified? So, with some logic on what goes and stays.

As an example, this csv extract has two lines. Each field but one is the same. The ID number  being "the same" means it is a "duplicate" for my purposes.

Both lines are not *completely* the same though.

The date in the final (7th) field of the csv file makes one entry older than the other.

```
ID12345,Here is some text,ABCDEFG,7,9,2022-08-18 20:15:00,2022-08-26 17:32:00
ID12345,Here is some text,ABCDEFG,7,9,2022-08-18 20:15:00,2022-09-11 22:15:00
```

Is it possible to gawk, cat, grep, cut, awk etc on the file and:

a) identify anything with a duplicate ID.
b) retain only the duplicates with the "newest" date in the last field.

Ideally I would need the first line left in place because that has the headings for the csv which is being fed into a database.

That is why this almost works well:

```
gawk -i inplace '!a[$0]++' *.csv
```

It actually seems to remove duplicates leaving one line in place however it does not have the logic to decide what to leave in place based on the oldest date value in the final field.

Can you please help...

Comment: Can you guarantee the second field not to become `"here is some text, too"`? Because these typical problems can be handled best with a csv-aware parser (like python with csv include).

Comment: Hi, thanks everything will be the same except for the last field which denotes a modified date. So, I just need to identify anything with the same i.d. and delete them all, with the exception of the most recently modified one... This seems to "do something" I don't understand these very powerful text editing tools --> gawk 'NR==1{print;next} $2>a[$7] {a[$7]=$2} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' delme.csv

Comment: Is resorting the data a problem (apart from the header line)?

Comment: I actually don't think so

Comment: Wait, you're inserting this into a _database_? Why not just do that and let the later entries with the same ID overwrite the earlier ones? The ID field has a UNIQUE constraint on them, right? And you can use ON CONFLICT REPLACE?

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates within **each** file independently or across **all** files? I mean if `ID12345` shows up in file1 and then shows up again in file7, is that second occurrence a duplicate to you or not? Do you care about retaining the original input order of the data lines in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to test for duplicates within each file, not across all files, and that you don't care about preserving input order of your data, his will do what you want using any versions of mandatory POSIX tools so it'll work on any Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
sep=','
for file in "$@"; do
    {
        head -n 1 "$file" &&
        tail -n 2 "$file" |
            sort -t "$sep" -r -k 7,7 |
            awk -F "$sep" '$1 != prev { print; prev=$1 }'
    } > "$tmp" &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "$file"
done
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
foo,bar
ID12345,Here is some text,ABCDEFG,7,9,2022-08-18 20:15:00,2022-08-26 17:32:00
ID12345,Here is some text,ABCDEFG,7,9,2022-08-18 20:15:00,2022-09-11 22:15:00
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file*
```

```
$ cat file
foo,bar
ID12345,Here is some text,ABCDEFG,7,9,2022-08-18 20:15:00,2022-09-11 22:15:00
```

Note that only `sort` above has to handle all of the input at once, the other tools just handle 1 line at a time, and `sort` is designed to handle large files by using demand paging, etc. so you're unlikely to run into memory issues even if your input files are massive.

If you DO want to retain the input line order then you can change the above to apply [the DSU idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367) to do that:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
sep=','
for file in "$@"; do
    awk -v OFS="$sep" '{ print (NR>1), NR, $0 }' "$file" |
        sort -t "$sep" -k1,1 -k9,9r |
        awk -F "$sep" 'NR==1{print; next} $1 != prev{ print; prev=$1 }' |
        sort -t "$sep" -k1,1 -k2,2n |
        cut -d "$sep" -f3- \
    > "$tmp" &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "$file"
done
```

but it does require a second `sort` after the lines have been selected to get the input back to it's original order.

If you really wanted to do it all using a single call to GNU awk while retaining input order then it'd be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
FNR == 1 {
    delete id2maxTs
    delete id2fnr
    delete fnr2input
    print
    next
}
{ id=$1; ts=$7 }
!(id in id2maxTs) || (ts > id2maxTs[id]) {
    if ( id in id2fnr ) {
        prevFnr = id2fnr[id]
        delete fnr2input[prevFnr]
    }
    id2maxTs[id]   = ts
    id2fnr[id]     = FNR
    fnr2input[FNR] = $0
}
ENDFILE {
    for ( i=1; i<=FNR; i++ ) {
        if ( i in fnr2input ) {
            print fnr2input[i]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ gawk -i inplace -f tst.awk file*
```

```
$ cat file
foo,bar
ID12345,Here is some text,ABCDEFG,7,9,2022-08-18 20:15:00,2022-08-26 17:32:00
```

That gawk script would retain the original input order but it would have to read all of each input file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the [mktime()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) function:

```
gawk -F, '
NR==1{ print; next }
{
    svn=dTime=$7
    gsub(/[-:]/, " ", dTime)
    dTime=mktime(dTime)
    sub(/,[^,]*$/, "")
}
dTime > gId[$0] {
    gId[$0]=dTime
    records[$0]=svn
}
END { for(rec in records) print rec, records[rec] }' infile
```

see [Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#index-PROCINFO-array-2) (`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`) to set the default for-loop traverses of an array when outputing.

Answer (score 0):

Combining `sort` with `awk`

```
#get header line
head -1 infile
#work on data
tail +2 infile | sort -t, -r -k7 | awk -F, '!seen[$1]++'
```

=> Reversely sorts by seventh field (the date field), i.e. newest entries first. Then prints lines with first unique ID only.

Caveats: extra commas in the strings; if same date appears for same ID, the line is taken as defined by the reverse sorting; date strings not using leading/padded zeros or mixed formats altogether